# ERROR [STDERR] Error: \Test_Reports\Suite_Report.html (The system cannot find the path specified)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss5.x

I have an old java project. I created war file for that project. I modified the path given in the project for example:

```
........

    old path=ReportUtil.startTesting(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Test_Reports//Suite_Report.html");
    new path=ReportUtil.startTesting("/Test_Reports/Suite_Report.html");

.......
```

While run the file it showing the message like this=:"ERROR [STDERR] Error: \Test_Reports\Suite_Report.html (The system cannot find the path specified)".

How can i overcome this error, I need suggestion from all of you thanks in advance.

**code**

```
`HybridFramework.java
--------------------
public static void startTesting()
{
ReportUtil.startTesting("/Test_Reports/Suite_Report.html");
}



ReportUtil.java
----------------
public static void startTesting(String filename)
{
String indexResultFilename = filename;
String currentDir =  indexResultFilename.substring(0,indexResultFilename.lastIndexOf("/"));
FileWriter fstream =null;
BufferedWriter out =null;
try{
 fstream = new FileWriter(filename); //--------->here only showing the   error "The system cannot find the path specified"
 out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `new path=ReportUtil.startTesting("//Test_Reports//Suite_Report.html")`

Comment: Hi tried your suggestion now it showing the error as "The network path was not found" but befor it shows the message as "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: What about `new path=ReportUtil.startTesting(".//Test_Reports//Suite_Report.html")`

Comment: I given the new path=ReportUtil.startTesting("//Test_Reports//Suite_Report.html") it shows the error message as ERROR [STDERR] Error: \\Test_Reports\Suite_Report.html (The network path was not found)

Comment: Maybe just `new path=ReportUtil.startTesting("Test_Reports//Suite_Report.html")`? Try absolute path also...

Comment: I tried your all suggestion that is also not working. It showing the error as "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Maybe this could help you... http://www.coderanch.com/t/578029/jforum/redeploying-JBOSS

I assume you use JBoss...

Comment: yes I am using jboss, But you refer the above link that is also not working.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... posting some additional code might help.

Answer (score 0):

That `//` is suspicious and should have been `/` here.

I assume that the directory Test_Reports was created manually (and on Linux with sufficient privileges).

Also note that `FileWriter` uses the current platform encoding. If you want to deal with full Unicode, better use `OutputStreamWriter` with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. In the HTML a correspondig meta charset statement should be added.